# Why can I post text with JLabel but not with .drawString

Tags: java, swing

Im not sure what I'm doing wrong as i've seen it done this way countless times before in various open source programs and games.  below is my code that is giving me the error that g2 isn't a assigned variable?  im confused..

```
package scratch;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/* FrameDemo.java requires no other files. */
public class okay {
    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("helllo", JLabel.CENTER);
        emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint ( Graphics g ){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawString("hello",0,0);
}





    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
                paint(g2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you should most likely be calling `repaint()` and not `paint()` explicitly and secondly `paint()` should be overriding a components paint method.

Comment: There's no reason to call `repaint()` when first displaying the GUI. Swing will paint it.

Comment: @vandale: sorry, but your comment is off base -- the OP doesn't **call** paint anywhere. Instead in his code he is trying to override the paint method, but since his class extends no Swing JComponent class, the paint method will do nothing useful for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class extends no Swing component and so the paint method is not an override and does nothing. Instead you should have your class extend JPanel, **put this JPanel into a JFrame**, and override paintComponent. Also, 1) always give methods that you *think* are overriding super methods the `@Override` annotation. This way the compiler would have told you immediately that what you're doing is wrong. 2) Don't guess when it comes to learning new Java features -- look at and study the appropriate tutorial before trying this stuff. Here the painting in Swing tutorial would have answered these questions for you.

---

e.g.,

```
public class Foo extends JPanel {
  @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawString("hello", 0, 20);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(new Foo());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: i want to use the g.drawString instead of the label to write text out

Comment: @wilkers: I know, and my answer addresses this. If my answer confuses you, please specify exactly what confuses you. But again first, go to the Swing tutorials to see how to do Swing graphics correctly because you're just guessing. Please start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).

Comment: thanks for the link, how would i go about this using AWT instead of swing?

Comment: @wilkers: you wouldn't. It would be foolish in the extreme to want to use AWT.